# Unable to delete file, even when running as root

Tags: permissions, rhel, root, rm

I am in the process of migrating a machine from RHEL 4 to 5. Rather than actually do an upgrade we have created a new VM (both machines are in a cloud) and I am in the process of copying across data between the two.

I have come across the following file, which I need to remove from the new machine but am unable to, even when running as root:

```
-rw-------  1 2003 2003  219 jan 11 14:22 .bash_history
```

This file is inside /home/USER/, where USER is the account of the guy who built the machine. He doesn't have an account on the old machine, so I am trying to remove his home folder so that the new machine tallies with the old one, but I get the following error:

```
rm: ne peut enlever `.bash_history': Opération non permise
```

(translated from the French: cannot remove XXX, operation not permitted)

I have tried using the following command but this has made no difference:

```
chattr -i .bash_history
```

Is the only choice to create a user with the ID 2003, or is there another way around it?

---

## Edit

I have tried using `rm -f`, and I get the same error. I get the same kind of error using `chmod 777` first.

I have been able to `chown` the folder that contains the file I am trying to delete, so it is:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 jan 24 15:58 USER
```

---

## Edit2

Running the `lsattr` command as suggested by Angus gave the following output:

```
-----a------- USER/.bash_history
------------- USER/..
------------- USER/.
```

The file is flagged as append-only - on changing this flag using `chattr -a .bash_history` I was able to delete the file.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Check the permissions of the **directory**. To delete a file inside it, it should be writable by you

```
chmod ugo+w .
```

and not immutable or append-only:

```
chattr -i -a .
```

Check with `ls -la` and `lsattr -a`.

Comment: thanks.. I had to run this on named* files that didnt not clean up after yum erase bind in Centos 7 minimal

Comment: Unfortunately, for `/vendor/laracasts/generators/.git/objects/pack/`, when I run `chattr -i -a .`, I get `chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on .`, and I can't `rm` the pesky `.idx` file that Composer left behind (because "Operation not permitted").

Comment: Ahhh, one workaround for me was to exit out of my Laravel Homestead Vagrant VirtualBox back into Windows 10 (still using Git Bash) and `rm` the files from there. Then `composer update` was able to complete.

Comment: `chattr -i -a` worked.

Comment: Even after using Linux for nearly 10 years, I keep on learning new stuff. Never heard about the immutable attribute before!

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem but had tried both permissions and chattr previously to no avail. Root in Terminal. CD to Directory.

However what worked for me was to check permissions of directory where troublesome file was located - if ok proceed to:

```
chmod ugo+w filename
```

this failed - then:

```
chattr -i -a filename
```

which was accepted - then

```
chmod ugo+w
```

which was accepted

```
rm filename
```

and it was gone.

Fedora 25 on hp workstation.

Comment: 'chmod ugo+w filename" totally did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

'sudo' can run the 'rm' command using the same user.group

**NOTE**: not sure if this will also work for ids like you have.

Example:

```
ls /path/to/dir_being_deleted
  drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody   4096 Mar  8 06:55 .
  drwxrwxrwx 7 nfsnobody nfsnobody   4096 Mar  8 06:57 ..
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody      0 Mar  8 06:55 filename.txt

sudo -u nfsnobody -g nfsnobody rm -rf /path/to/dir_being_deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer using `chattr`, I ran into this issue myself
when trying to remove an unwanted directory and found that using

```
chattr -RVf -i <directory>
```

solved my issue. 
The directory had dozens of folders inside, several levels deep, and

```
lsattr -la *
```

showed me that the majority of the subfolder contents
were still immutable
despite running a basic `chattr -i -a <directory>`
as mentioned by others here. 
I found the `-RVf` options when I finally read the `man chattr`. 
Whoda thunk reading the directions...