# Can move but can't remove empty /home directory (root, no attr, RW filesystem, not mount point, not busy)

Tags: arch-linux, btrfs

I can move it but `rmdir` and `rm -rf` fail even as root (`failed to remove '/home': Operation not permitted`). `lsattr` is all `----------`.

Whenever I `mv /home /home.bakN` I get directories that are also unremovable plus a recreated /home with the same restriction after I reboot ("single" mode). I can remove everything else, I can create new files and directories, not a read-only partition.

I used to use a /home partition but I disabled it (replaced /home with /media/home in /etc/fstab) and I can successfully use a /home directory. I just don't understand why I can't remove it (again: it's not busy and no application uses it and no /home user is logged in).

Comment: Is `/home` exported via NFS?  Is `/home` an automount point for `autofs`?  (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/autofs.5.html)

Comment: maybe inside /home there are some files/directory with a or i attribute? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/unable-to-delete-file-even-when-running-as-root

Comment: As I showed, /home is empty (I would have gotten a different error message for that).

Answer (score 3):

It's a btrfs-specific issue: /home is a subvolume.

`btrfs subvolume list -a /parent` shows all subvolumes and `btrfs subvolume delete dirname` deletes them.